# confusion about short data type format specifier in C

Tags: c, undefined-behavior, short, format-specifiers, type-promotion

Consider following program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    short a=9;
    //printf("%hi\n",a);
    printf("%d",a);  // LINE 6
}
```

According to [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_data_types) the format specifier for short type (signed) is **`%hi`**
Is the **short** type variable always gets promoted automatically to **int** before performing any operation on it? Is it undefined behavior ,
If I use %d format specifier to print the value of variable in this program? I compiled it using gcc **`-Wall -Wextra -WFormat`** options but still 
compiler isn't showing any single warning. Why?

Answer (score 3):

```
printf("%hi\n", a);
```

`a` is promoted to `int` as per the rules of default argument promotion of variadic functions.

Anyway as you use `h` specifier the implementation is allowed to expect the `int` value is within `SHRT_MIN` or `SHRT_MAX` limits. Passing a value outside the bounds is undefined behavior.

Of course `printf("%i\n", a);` is also valid because of the `int` promotion of `a` so using `%hi` conversion specification is not very usual.

Comment: where can I find the  rules of default argument promotion of variadic functions. ?

Comment: @PravasiMeet see C Standard, in C99 see 6.5.2.2p7 for rules of promotion with variadic functions and 6.5.2.2p6 for what is the default argument promotions.

Comment: ok thanks. I found this useful also: https://www.eskimo.com/~scs/cclass/int/sx4cb.html

Comment: False! The C standard only says (ISO 9899:2011§7.21.6.1¶7#`h`) “the argument will have been promoted according to the integer promotions, but its value shall be converted to short int or unsigned short int before printing” For me this does explicitly specify defined behaviour for `int` values outside the range from `SHORT_MIN` to `SHORT_MAX`, where the behaviour is as if the parameter was converted by `printf` to `signed short`/ `unsigned short` before printing.

Comment: @FUZxxl I don't agree! That's not my reading!  The full sentence is *"Specifies that a following d, i, o, u, x, or X conversion specifier applies to a short int or unsigned short int argument (the argument will have been promoted according to the integer promotions, but its value shall be converted to short int or unsigned short int before printing);"* the first words explicitly say the argument before the promotion is a `unsigned short` / `short`

Comment: @ouah Hm... The wording is definitely unclear. Let me ask a question about this.

Comment: @ouah Let's see what comes out of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/32529239/417501).