# Is it illegal to use the h or hh length modifiers when the corresponding argument to printf was not a short / char?

Tags: c, printf, language-lawyer, undefined-behavior, short

The `printf` family of functions provide a series of length modifiers, two of them being `hh` (denoting a `signed char` or `unsigned char` argument promoted to `int`) and `h` (denoting a `signed short` or `unsigned short` argument promoted to `int`). Historically, these length modifiers have only been introduced to create symmetry with the length modifiers of `scanf` and are rarely used for `printf`.

Here is an excerpt of ISO 9899:2011 §7.21.6.1 “The fprintf function” ¶7:

> 7 The length modifiers and their meanings are:
>
> - `hh` Specifies that a following `d`, `i`, `o`, `u`, `x`, or `X` conversion specifier applies to a `signed char` or `unsigned char` argument (the argument will have been promoted according to the integer promotions, but its value shall be converted to `signed char` or `unsigned char` before printing); or that a following `n` conversion specifier applies to a pointer to a signed char
>     argument.
> - `h` Specifies that a following `d`, `i`, `o`, `u`, `x`, or `X` conversion specifier applies to a `short int` or `unsigned short int`argument (the argument will have been promoted according to the integer promotions, but its value shall be converted to `short int` or `unsigned short int` before printing); or that a following `n` conversion specifier applies to a pointer to a short `int` argument.
> - ...

Ignoring the case of the `n` conversion specifier, what do these almost identical paragraphs say about the behaviour of `h` and `hh`?

- In [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32528670/417501), it is claimed that passing an argument that is outside the range of a `signed char`, `signed short`, `unsigned char`, or `unsigned short` resp. for a conversion specification with an `h` or `hh` length modifier resp. is *undefined behaviour,* as the argument wasn't converted from type `char`, `short`, etc. resp. before.
- I claim that the function operates in a well-defined manner for every value of type `int` and that `printf` behaves as if the parameter was converted to `char`, `short`, etc. resp. before conversion.
- One could also claim that invoking the function with an argument that was not of the corresponding type before default argument promotion is undefined behaviour, but this seems abstruse.

Which of these three interpretations of §7.21.6.1¶7 (if at all) is correct?

Comment: I made the first claim (see linked answer). I actually do think that if we are pedantic with the words used in the paragraph my claim stands (the argument before promotion is a `short` variant) but the spirit of this paragraph/C makes `FUZxxl`'s claim maybe more likely.

Comment: I think the first approach is correct. The conversion routine may very well expect the limited range, thus use an optimized version (just think of a 8 or 16 bit CPU). Not sure, if the input argument has to be of the same type. Question is, how the format-string parser can tell a "true" `int` input argument from a `short`/etc. converted to `int`. Another aspect might be inlining by the compiler. At worst it might inhibit optimization, but nothing else, as it has to behave the same.

Comment: This line is somewhat unclear - `%h......but its value shall be converted to short int or unsigned short int before printing)` . So does it mean that it can hold values greater than `unsigned short int  /short int` as it is undergone integer promotion ? And if so than value it hold is converted back to its original variable type ? What will be its outcome ?

Comment: If you  pass a 64 bit integer, and us `%hhd`, then  you are going to hurt, because this will take up 8 bytes, and `printf` will expect it to take 4 (windows and Linux x86 anyway)

Comment: @Ben Yes of course. I should have made clearer that I was talking about `signed` or `unsigned int` arguments, as these are the types expected for `h` and `hh` due to default argument promotions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The standard specifies:

> If any argument is not the correct type for the corresponding conversion specification, the behavior is undefined.

[C2011 7.21.6.1/9]

What is meant by "the correct type", is conceivably open to interpretation, but the most plausible interpretation to me is the type that the conversion specification "applies to" as specified earlier in the same section, and as quoted, in part, in the question.  I take the *parenthetical* comments about argument promotion to be acknowledging the ordinary argument-passing rules, and avoiding any implication of these functions being special cases.  I do not take the parenthetic comments as relevant to determining the "correct type" of the argument.

What actually happens if you pass an argument of wider type than is correct for the conversion specification is a different question.  I am inclined to believe that the C system is unlikely to be implemented by anybody such that it makes a difference whether a `printf()` argument is actually a `char`, or whether it is an `int` whose value is in the range of `char`.  I assert, however, that it is valid behavior for the compiler to check argument type correspondence with the format, and to reject the program if there is a mismatch (because the required behavior in such a case is explicitly undefined).

On the other hand, I could certainly imagine `printf()` implementations that actually misbehave (print garbage, corrupt memory, eat your lunch) if the value of an argument is outside the range implied by the corresponding conversion specifier.  This also is permissible on account of the behavior being undefined.

Comment: Iif I pass an `int` for a conversion with `h`, then the argument type does match as `h` expects the type of “a signed or unsigned `short` after default argument promotion,” and `int` is that type.

Comment: @FUZxxl, no, you have misquoted.  The standard says `h` means the conversion specifier "applies to a short int or unsigned short int argument" -- end of thought.  It does remark upon argument promotion in that context, but that is a separate and subsidiary consideration, as indicated by those comments being parenthesized.

Comment: @JohnBollinger: so the code in linked question doesn't invoke UB If i use %d format specifier because of implicit promotion. right?

Comment: @PravasiMeet, in the strictest interpretation of the standard -- which I have in fact advanced -- it *does* produce undefined behavior if an argument of type `short int` is given for a field with specifier `%d`.  I have claimed that the default argument promotions do not factor in to the required type correspondance.  In practice, I could imagine a compiler rejecting it, but if the code is accepted then I don't see how there could be a runtime problem.

Comment: Okay, so after asking my local UNIX greybeard (who's one of the authors of POSIX) and testing various recent and historical implementations of the C programming language, it seems that the intent of `h` and `hh` was to be able to print out the values of characters with the high bit turned on without having to convert them before (`%u` would print a wrong value due to sign-extension for a char), and the desired behaviour is that of a simple masking with `& 0xff` or similar. Historic C implementations (e.g. ULTRIX) don't know h, but all that do have the aforementioned behaviour.

Comment: @FUZxxl, ultimately, only WG14 can provide an authoritative answer.  If they were to issue an official interpretation of this point then it is likely that they would consider intent -- insofar as that can be determined -- and historic behavior, but unless they issue a full-fledged correction they must work within the text as written, and a different interpretation than I have given would seem pretty contrived to me.  In practice, however, it probably doesn't matter.  Even if the behavior is formally undefined here, it's unlikely that you'll find an implementation where it's actually a problem.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Yeah, that sounds like a sensible assumption.

Comment: In http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.4.2.2p3, there is a line `printf("%s\n", __func__)`. For `%s`, the standard says that the argument shall be a pointer to char. `__func__` is not a pointer to char, it has type `const char[<some N>]`.

Comment: @LanguageLawyer, footnotes are non-normative.  I am not sure I would advance the same strict interpretation of the standard today, more than four years later, but neither am I interested in taking the matter up again at this time.

Comment: _footnotes are non-normative_ I know, but, unfortunately, it seems (not from this footnote alone) the intent is that requirements on argument types apply to types after promotion...