# is using int variables as char variables OK?

Tags: c, char, int

so my question is why do some people use int variables as char variables.
exemple

```
int main()

{

 int i;

 scanf("%c",&i);

printf ("%c",i);

}
```

thank's in advance

Comment: `scanf("%c",&i);` is wrong.  So `printf ("%c",i);` Portable results can not be obtained.

Comment: did you even try your code? Online compiler says it is not okay: https://ideone.com/clSfwc

Comment: @mch This code compile with warning,  if not `-Werror` flag set.

Comment: Apart from the posted sample, all (?) of the library functions which one might suppose would take a `char` argument and/or return a `char` function value, use `int`. Such as `getchar`, `strchr`, `toupper` and so on. In some cases this is so that an error condition can be returned, such a `EOF`, which can be distinguished from a `char` value.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY but it worked for me with out any error or warning

Comment: @BLUEPIXY i'm using code blocks with gnu gcc compiler

Comment: To different environment it may get a different result.(it's undefined behaviour)

Comment: **Always** enable compiler warnings!

Comment: "but it worked for me" does not mean it will under all circumstances, or even on a second call. Please think about the implications of **undefined** _behaviour_

Answer (score 4, accepted):

C's `char` is an integer type.  Its (numeric) values are most often used to represent characters, but that's a separate matter.

You can safely use a variable of type `int` to hold a value in the range of type `char`.  You can assign a `char` to an `int` or pass a `char` to a function expecting an int, both without a cast and without altering the value.

In certain places, `int` is used intentionally instead of `char` to represent characters.  The canonical case is probably the standard library's `getc()`, `fgetc()`, and `getchar()` functions, which need the range of an `int` to be able to represent `EOF` in addition to every possible `char` value.  Also, for historical reasons, some other functions declare `int` arguments to accept data expected to be of type `char`; `memset()` is one of the better known of these.

On the other hand, *pointers* to `int` and to `char` are *not* interchangeable.  As others pointed out, your `scanf()` call produces undefined behavior for that reason.

Generally speaking, you should use `char` rather than `int` to represent character data, unless there is a good, externally-driven reason to do otherwise (such as needing to handle the return value of `getchar()`).  Even more generally speaking, match data types correctly, being deliberate about where you allow type conversions to be performed.

Answer (score 2):

This -

```
scanf("%c",&i);
```

Wrong argument is passed (`%c` expects address of char ).It invokes *undefined behaviour* .

Comment: @lol  just  compile it with flags `-Wall -Werror` and see what you get .

Comment: If `char` is guaranteed to be **less or equal** to `int` (mostly less), why is it UB? You'll get a warning, but you'll have more than enough memory space to store it. It's wrong from the `scanf` point of view, which is waiting a `char *` and is getting an `int *`.

Comment: @EnzoFerber  I said **UB** in context of `scanf` only . Wrong argument if passed will cause it .

Comment: @lol And of  correct output , you know you can get anything if there is UB.

Comment: @EnzoFerber, for `printf()` the matter is open to interpretation, but see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32529239/is-it-illegal-to-use-the-h-or-hh-length-modifiers-when-the-corresponding-argumen/32529594#32529594) and similar questions and answers for a discussion of some of the issues.